# PowerShell: write-progress bar just disappears

Tags: powershell

So I have this for each loop .  The first thing I do in this loop is call one
of my cmdlets  witch amongst other things calls

```
 Write-Progress -Activity "Testing Progress" -Status "$($progressDisplay)% Complete."  -PercentComplete $progress -CurrentOperation "$($op)"
```

Each iteration of the loop takes from 30 minutes to 1 hour  But before the iteration is done the progress bar is gone.

I found nothing on that their is time limit , how to extend a time limit.

Progress is done by adding the data to each item in the list I foreach over.

```
Function Add-ProgressData{
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Object]$list,
        [Switch]$NoCmdletEntryOutput)
    Begin{}
    
    Process{

        # calcuatle what 1% progress would be for 
        # the given list

        $OnePercent = [math]::Round(100/([double]$list.Count),2)
  
        # calculate start value for progress

        $Currentpercent = $OnePercent

        # enumerate the list of add progress data for each item

        foreach($i in $list) {

            # add ProgressData properties to node 
            # and set it to the current progress data

            $CurrentProgressDsiplay = [math]::Round(($Currentpercent),0)

            $po = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Type = "Percent"
                CurrentProgress = $Currentpercent
                CurrentProgressDsiplay = $CurrentProgressDsiplay
                CurrentOperation = "Testing $($i.Type) $($i.string)"
            }

            Add-Member -InputObject $i -NotePropertyName ProgressData -NotePropertyValue $po

            # Calcualte the next progress percent

            $Currentpercent = $Currentpercent + $OnePercent

        }

     
       }

    End{}

 }
```

Here is what that data looks like for this specific list

```
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=2.78; CurrentProgressDsiplay=3; CurrentOperation=Testing …    
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=5.56; CurrentProgressDsiplay=6; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=8.34; CurrentProgressDsiplay=8; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=11.12; CurrentProgressDsiplay=11; CurrentOperation=Testing …    
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=13.9; CurrentProgressDsiplay=14; CurrentOperation=Testing …   
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=16.68; CurrentProgressDsiplay=17; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=19.46; CurrentProgressDsiplay=19; CurrentOperation=Testing …  
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=22.24; CurrentProgressDsiplay=22; CurrentOperation=Testing …    
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=25.02; CurrentProgressDsiplay=25; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=27.8; CurrentProgressDsiplay=28; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=30.58; CurrentProgressDsiplay=31; CurrentOperation=Testing …  
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=33.36; CurrentProgressDsiplay=33; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=36.14; CurrentProgressDsiplay=36; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=38.92; CurrentProgressDsiplay=39; CurrentOperation=Testing …  
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=41.7; CurrentProgressDsiplay=42; CurrentOperation=Testing …   
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=44.48; CurrentProgressDsiplay=44; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=47.26; CurrentProgressDsiplay=47; CurrentOperation=Testing …  
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=50.04; CurrentProgressDsiplay=50; CurrentOperation=Testing …  
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=52.82; CurrentProgressDsiplay=53; CurrentOperation=Testing …  
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=55.6; CurrentProgressDsiplay=56; CurrentOperation=Testing …   
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=58.38; CurrentProgressDsiplay=58; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=61.16; CurrentProgressDsiplay=61; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=63.94; CurrentProgressDsiplay=64; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=66.72; CurrentProgressDsiplay=67; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=69.5; CurrentProgressDsiplay=70; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=72.28; CurrentProgressDsiplay=72; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=75.06; CurrentProgressDsiplay=75; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=77.84; CurrentProgressDsiplay=78; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=80.62; CurrentProgressDsiplay=81; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=83.4; CurrentProgressDsiplay=83; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=86.18; CurrentProgressDsiplay=86; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=88.96; CurrentProgressDsiplay=89; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=91.74; CurrentProgressDsiplay=92; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=94.52; CurrentProgressDsiplay=95; CurrentOperation=Testing …
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=97.3; CurrentProgressDsiplay=97; CurrentOperation=Testing …   
@{Type=Percent; CurrentProgress=100.08; CurrentProgressDsiplay=100; CurrentOperation=Testing …
```

The other parts

```
foreach( $g in $list) {


        try {

            #
            #  Start test case
            #

            $tc = Start-TestCase -name "Test"  -Progress $g
```

....

The Start-Test case calls   Out-ProgressData -Object $Progress

```
 Function Out-ProgressData{
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Object]$Object,
        [Switch]$NoCmdletEntryOutput)
    Begin{}
    
    Process{

        # prep variables 

        $progressData = $Object.ProgressData

        $progress         = $progressData.CurrentProgress
        $progressDisplay  = $progressData.CurrentProgressDsiplay
        $op               = $ProgressData.CurrentOperation

        # Disaplyes progress

        Write-Progress -Activity "Testing Progress" -Status "$($progressDisplay)% Complete."  -PercentComplete $progress -CurrentOperation "$($op)"
             
       }

    End{}

 }
```

Comment: How is `$progress` being calculated? We need more details to understand where the problem could be.

Comment: Please share how `$Progress` is being calculated. That could be the culprit in this case just like Santi points out as well.

Comment: `Add-ProgressData` never calls `Write-Progress`? How are these two pieces of code related?

Comment: `PercentComplete` is usually calculated with something like `$counter++ / $list.Count*100`. The function you've posted, as Mathias stated, doesn't seem to be related with this calculation.

Comment: The  first cmdlet in my foreach loop get passed the current list node and it calls write-progress.  That call is the first code snippet I posted.  If I do nothing but wait a minute in the for each loop , it works perfectly .

Comment: @deetle So you do `Add-ProgressData | Write-Progress ...`? That doesn't make much sense, `Add-ProgressData` doesn't appear to output anything.

Comment: I added the other parts

Comment: To put it short, there is no bug with `Write-Progress`, a loop can run for days and, as long as, `PercentComplete` has the right data it will show until the loop has finished. What you're experiencing is a bug with your code which you'll need to debug unless someone else is kind enough to debug it for you. Adding the progress as a member to the objects is not only unorthodox, and quite confusing but also quite inefficient.

Comment: I don't think it is with my code.  I too just ran a mark up where it sits their for an hour.    But it always seems to disappear when I run cmdlets from a 3rd party specific module .

Comment: Is their a means to make sure that a module I have not control over , to suppress any progress bar activity it might or night not have ?

Comment: Please always include as much detail as possible when you first post, to get the most attention. This includes the output. I think what Santiago is correct imo as well

Comment: It not mine code , its the code in some huge modules I have no control over is messing with my progress window.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a bug in PowerShell/Write-Progress but it might not be related. We've got a laptop that run some sketchy M365 PowerShell scripts. It's on all the time and the PowerShell window is often left open for weeks. Our script uses progress bars and occasionally they just stop working. Stop the script and start again - no progress. Re-open PowerShell and the progress bars start working.